# Pyserial does not work when Pexpect exists

Tags: python, pyserial, pexpect

I would like to communicate with a router(changing ip address) using Pyserial. It works when I just run the following code:

```
def ipaddr_set():
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty_dgrp_aa_0",baudrate=115200)
    ser.open()
    channel =fdpexpect.fdspawn(ser.fd)
    channel.send("\n\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send("\nusername\npassword\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send("\n ip-adress 114.293.232.20\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send("exit\n")
    ser.close()
```

But if I add a function using pexpect:

```
def ftp_firmware_update():
    child = pexpect.spawn('ftp 114.293.232.20')
    child.delaybeforesend = 0.1
    child.expect('(?i)name .*: ')
    child.sendline('username')
    child.expect('(?i)Password')
    child.sendline('pass')
    child.expect('ftp> ')
    child.sendline('put firmware.bin')
    child.expect('Upgrade')
    child.sendline('close')
    child.expect('221')
    print child.before,child.after
    child.sendline('quit')
    child.close()
    print "Upgrade firmware finished, sleep..."
    time.sleep(20)
```

The ipaddr_set() does not work well(it gets executed but the ip is not changed). Anyone has solution to such situation?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: updating the firmware probably resets the settings. Update first, then change ip.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian actually I did update first and change ip afterwards (and that is the purpose of changing ip address). Sorry for the confusion. But it does not work...